# unrecognized expression using template literals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Executing this code:

```
let pathb = $('.cslideract').attr('data-pathb');
console.log(pathb);
```

I get the following result: `anima/01/inc`.

Now I try to use it in this function:

```
if($(`.partslider[data-pathb=${pathb}]`).length > 0){console.log('323');}
```

I am getting this error:

`unrecognized expression: .partslider[data-pathb=anima/01/inc/]`

I tried the same with `let pathb = 'anything'` and it works, but my variable is `anima/01/inc`

Comment: Did you try quoting your template? (e.g. ``$(`.partslider[data-pathb="${pathb}"]`)``)

Comment: In the CSS selector expression the attribute value has to be quoted.

Comment: @Pointy,  I can't see any `css selector` in my code

Comment: The string you pass to jQuery is a CSS selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the jQuery docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), you need to use quotes around the value in attribute selectors. Try this:

```
if($(`.partslider[data-pathb="${pathb}"]`).length > 0){console.log('323');}
```

This is also true of [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Comment: Pretty sure you only have to use quotes when you have special characters (maybe non-alphanumeric?)

Comment: No, they're needed for [valid identifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors), and jQuery's page shows you need a quoted string if it's not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes `""` enclosing the literal

```js
let pathb = $('.cslideract').attr('data-pathb');
console.log(pathb);


if($(`.partslider[data-pathb="${pathb}"]`).length > 0){console.log('323');}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cslideract" data-pathb="anima/01/inc"></div>
<div class="partslider" data-pathb="anima/01/inc"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may escape characters having a special meaning in a CSS selector ([$.escapeSelector()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/)):

```js
let pathb = 'anima/01/inc';

console.log(`.partslider[data-pathb=${$.escapeSelector(pathb)}]`);

if($(`.partslider[data-pathb=${$.escapeSelector(pathb)}]`).length > 0){
    console.log('323');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```